# Yii2: how to write logs within Codeception?

Tags: logging, yii2-advanced-app, codeception

I've installed Yii2 from the box and want to write logs within codeception test. No any errors, but logs is empty. What I do wrong?

in frontend/config/main.php log is enabled:
`'bootstrap' => ['log'],`

```
<?php

namespace frontend\tests\unit\models;

class SomeTest extends \Codeception\Test\Unit
{

    public function testLogMessage()
    {
        \Yii::error('something bad occurred');
    }

}
```

What I expect:
To see the logs in frontend/runtime after `codecept run` executing.

Actual result:
Logs is empty.